# Can I have static pages in Active Admin resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have setup Active Admin in my rails app and all is well and working fine.

I am having to use different fields for different pages in my site and I cannot just create a pages resource and add pages as each page has to have different fields for types of content on there, and they need to be arranged in a specific way.

Does anyone have any tips on how this could be done with active admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pages resource and customize the form to be dynamic.

You can do:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Page do
  form :partial => "form"
end

#app/views/admin/pages/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for [:admin, @page] do |f| %>
  <% # Your form stuff and maybe some JS magic to add dynamic fields %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah so in my Pages resource I have already setup I could just stick something like this in there and just call form something else and reference it that way? How could it be used for 2 pages one called 'What we do' and the other 'Spaces and Facilities'? These have basically 2 completely different layouts, so when you go into active admin and add the new pages each area needs to have custom fields.

Comment: You can use JS for that. Or you can just treat different types of pages as different resources.

Comment: So are you saying instead of creating one resource for all pages just create different resources named for instance 'what-we-do' and 'spaces-and-facilities'? Or create Pages and then have types in that? Sorry my knowledge is okay but how could I create types inside it?

Comment: These are the two alternatives, it's up to you to choose what's best for your case. I think have a form with dynamic fields is the best option. Have a look at this http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms.